# Link posted through open graph does not work on facebook mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-opengraph

We are posting a link through our app using OpenGraph.  If we view the link from Facebook using a browser it displays perfectly and the link goes to the correct place.  If we view from the Facebook mobile app on iOS or Android it does not.

This is the correct link:[http://meca.st/v/6wEhOTQfh][1]
It displays perfectly when clicked on from Facebook in a browser.

This is the link that shows up when clicked from Facebook Mobile: ft=qid.5735821438092661368%3Amf_story_key.129730237160681">http://meca.st/?ref=feed&refid=7&*ft*=qid.5735821438092661368%3Amf_story_key.129730237160681

Basically, it appears to lose our direct location, instead going to the primary site URL.  The strange thing is that it works from everywhere except from within facebook's mobile apps.

And if we post the link manually it works fine.  It's only when we submit through OpenGraph.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jason

```
Here is the code that initiates the post:
[[manager facebook] postToWall:[captionTextField text] linkURL:[[manager mediaItem] playbackURL] imageURL:[[[manager mediaItem] thumbnails] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

[captionTextField text] - text entered by user
[[manager mediaItem] playbackURL] - playback URL returned by the server
[[[manager mediaItem] thumbnails] objectAtIndex:0] - First Thumbnail URL sent by the server

Here is the postToWall method

```
- (void)postToWall:(NSString *)message linkURL:(NSString *)linkURL imageURL:(NSString *)imageURL {
NSMutableDictionary *postArguments = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

if (message != nil)
    [postArguments setObject:message forKey:@"message"];

if (linkURL != nil)
    [postArguments setObject:linkURL forKey:@"link"];

if (imageURL != nil)
    [postArguments setObject:imageURL forKey:@"picture"];

 _action = MC_FB_STATE_2;

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:postArguments   andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I don't understand how you're posting the link. Can you show the code that you're using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Just updated my main post with the code.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like objective c, which I'm not familiar with so I can't help with that. Maybe you can run a network sniffer and check what's the exact request that is sent to facebook?

Comment: @user1359782 Did you get this fixed? Pls revert if so. Seeing same issue today (Jul 28)